# how to run doctrine.php in command prompt

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

I'm trying to use Doctrine with Zend, I have copied the doctrine.php and doctrine file in the script folder in the Source Files folder.
However when I type in command prompt following command: "php doctrine.php" by entering in the scripts folder, Nothing happens, there is no error printed, the cursor just goes to next line. Can someone please tell me how can I use doctrine.php.

Comment: Which version of Doctrine, 1.2 or 2.0? This sounds like you're using Guilherme's [integration suite](https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/ZendFramework1-Doctrine2) but could you please clarify?

Comment: @Phil Brown, Yes, Im using Guilherme's integration suite for Doctrine V2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Guilherme's integration suite, you need to do a couple of things.

1. Download / clone the Doctrine Common, DBAL and ORM libraries and make sure they're available in your include path. For this, I usually just copy the `lib/Doctrine` code from each into my project's `library` folder. If using git, you can add them as subtree splits but that's a topic for another time ;-)
2. You also need the Symfony Console and Yaml namespaces. Again, it's easiest to place them in your project's `library` folder under `library/Symfony/Component/Console` and `library/Symfony/Component/Yaml`. These usually come as submodule dependencies in the Doctrine libraries but you can also get them from their github pages

   - [Console](https://github.com/symfony/Console)
   - [Yaml](https://github.com/symfony/Yaml)
3. Remove the `bootstrap('Config')` call from the `doctrine.php` script. Don't know what Guilherme was thinking there :-)

That's it, from there it should work as expected.